# Retirar informação select html

Tags: php, html, selected-option

Estou com uma página que tem um select e queria poder saber qual foi a opção escolhida no select

```html
<html>
<body>
   <select class="form-control qa-product-options__quantity" name="quantidade" id="quantity">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="33">33</option>
        <option value="34">34</option>
        <option value="35">35</option>
        <option value="36">36</option>
        <option value="37">37</option>
        <option value="38">38</option>
        <option value="39">39</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="41">41</option>
        <option value="42">42</option>
        <option value="43">43</option>
        <option value="44">44</option>
        <option value="45">45</option>
        <option value="46">46</option>
        <option value="47">47</option>
        <option value="48">48</option>
        <option value="49">49</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="51">51</option>
        <option value="52">52</option>
        <option value="53">53</option>
        <option value="54">54</option>
        <option value="55">55</option>
        <option value="56">56</option>
        <option value="57">57</option>
        <option value="58">58</option>
        <option value="59">59</option>
        <option value="60">60</option>
        <option value="61">61</option>
        <option value="62">62</option>
        <option value="63">63</option>
        <option value="64">64</option>
        <option value="65">65</option>
        <option value="66">66</option>
        <option value="67">67</option>
        <option value="68">68</option>
        <option value="69">69</option>
        <option value="70">70</option>
        <option value="71">71</option>
        <option value="72">72</option>
        <option value="73">73</option>
        <option value="74">74</option>
        <option value="75">75</option>
        <option value="76">76</option>
        <option value="77">77</option>
        <option value="78">78</option>
        <option value="79">79</option>
        <option value="80">80</option>
        <option value="81">81</option>
        <option value="82">82</option>
        <option value="83">83</option>
        <option value="84">84</option>
        <option value="85">85</option>
        <option value="86">86</option>
        <option value="87">87</option>
        <option value="88">88</option>
        <option value="89">89</option>
        <option value="90">90</option>
        <option value="91">91</option>
        <option value="92">92</option>
        <option value="93">93</option>
        <option value="94">94</option>
        <option value="95">95</option>
        <option value="96">96</option>
        <option value="97">97</option>
        <option value="98">98</option>
        <option value="99">99</option>
      </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você for usar php, e esse select esta dentro de um form, você pode fazer assim.

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <select class="form-control qa-product-options__quantity" name="quantidade" id="quantity">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="16">16</option>
      <option value="17">17</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="23">23</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>
      <option value="26">26</option>
      <option value="27">27</option>
      <option value="28">28</option>
      <option value="29">29</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="31">31</option>
      <option value="32">32</option>
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="34">34</option>
      <option value="35">35</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="37">37</option>
      <option value="38">38</option>
      <option value="39">39</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="41">41</option>
      <option value="42">42</option>
      <option value="43">43</option>
      <option value="44">44</option>
      <option value="45">45</option>
      <option value="46">46</option>
      <option value="47">47</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>
      <option value="49">49</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="51">51</option>
      <option value="52">52</option>
      <option value="53">53</option>
      <option value="54">54</option>
      <option value="55">55</option>
      <option value="56">56</option>
      <option value="57">57</option>
      <option value="58">58</option>
      <option value="59">59</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
      <option value="61">61</option>
      <option value="62">62</option>
      <option value="63">63</option>
      <option value="64">64</option>
      <option value="65">65</option>
      <option value="66">66</option>
      <option value="67">67</option>
      <option value="68">68</option>
      <option value="69">69</option>
      <option value="70">70</option>
      <option value="71">71</option>
      <option value="72">72</option>
      <option value="73">73</option>
      <option value="74">74</option>
      <option value="75">75</option>
      <option value="76">76</option>
      <option value="77">77</option>
      <option value="78">78</option>
      <option value="79">79</option>
      <option value="80">80</option>
      <option value="81">81</option>
      <option value="82">82</option>
      <option value="83">83</option>
      <option value="84">84</option>
      <option value="85">85</option>
      <option value="86">86</option>
      <option value="87">87</option>
      <option value="88">88</option>
      <option value="89">89</option>
      <option value="90">90</option>
      <option value="91">91</option>
      <option value="92">92</option>
      <option value="93">93</option>
      <option value="94">94</option>
      <option value="95">95</option>
      <option value="96">96</option>
      <option value="97">97</option>
      <option value="98">98</option>
      <option value="99">99</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="verifica">Verifica</button>
  </form>

  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['verifica'])){
    echo $_POST['quantidade'];
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda @Rafa funcionou

Comment: Tamo junto. Sucesso no projeto.

Comment: já agora sabe-me dizer como faço para por isso dentro de uma variável?

Comment: você quer dizer o $_POST['quantidade']; ?

Comment: sim exactamente

Comment: Se você pretende usar essa variável entro desse mesmo arquivo você pode fazer Ex: $quantiade = $_POST['quantidade']; -  se for enviar para outra página poe usar Sessão, ou enviar pela URL

Comment: muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando Jquery

```
$('#quantity').find(":selected")
```

O análogo em javascript puro é

```
var e = document.getElementById("quantity");
var selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```